# AngularJS data-binding

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I have two code examples that work good, but I don't understand the difference. 
So, **the first** is:

**AngularJS:**

```
$scope.state = {presentation: true};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-class="{{state.presentation}} ? 'on' : 'off'"></div>
```

And **the second** one:

**AngularJS:**

```
$scope.presentation = true;
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-class="presentation ? 'on' : 'off'"></div>
```

Why can't I use something like this in the 2-nd example:

```
<div ng-class="{{presentation}} ? 'on' : 'off'"></div>
```

When I use {{ }} with `$scope.presentation = true;` it doesn't work in ng-class, but I can use {{presentation}} like the text, I mean `<div>{{presentation}}</div>` and it works good. Why?

But with `$scope.state = {presentation: true};` I can use {{presentation}} even in ng-class and it works good.

What the difference?

Comment: Probalby it's caused by writing/reading to different scope. Can you put your code in a plunker?

Comment: `div>{{presentation}}</div>` is this working in your 2nd example.

Comment: I have tried what you expect.Its working fine. Here is the plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/b2JzP55QuhV3dDCLhof0?p=preview

Comment: Also you there is no need of interpolation you can use it as plain JavaScript object or using  primitive type.  http://plnkr.co/edit/b2JzP55QuhV3dDCLhof0?p=preview

Comment: off class doesn't work because  bothe $scope.presentation  and $scope.state = {presentation: true}; are set to true.If you set anyone of this to false it show red that is 'off' class is applied.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN, yes. Sorry. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should'nt use an expression inside a ng-attribute like that. And it will fail (without or without the state object) :

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '?' not a primary
>   expression at column 2 of the expression [ ? 'on' : 'off'] starting at
>   [? 'on' : 'off'].

That's normal because angularJs executes it as an angularJS [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), so when you're typing :

```
<div ng-class="presentation ? 'on' : 'off'"></div>
```

Internally angularJS executes it as an expression and it can be written also like that :

```
<div class="{{presentation ? 'on' : 'off'}}"></div>
```